# How to obtain ready-to-execute queries?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to obtain `SQL` queries with inlined parameters of EF context? 
I would like to be able to copy-paste queries into management studio and execute them.

I work with `ctx.Database.Log` delegate, but it traces queries with parameters' values placed inside comments, eg:

```
   .... WHERE [Extent1].[Name] = @p__linq__0

   -- p__linq__0: 'ApproveReminder' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
```

Which are not runnable without first editing them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you can do this with SQL Server Profiler.

Run it, and then set up a profile watching the server that EF is connecting to. While it's running, execute your code so that the EF query you're interested in runs against the server. Then stop the profile.

If you peruse what it's recorded, you should be able to identify your query quite easily. Then click on it and the full query text will appear in the window at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately the traced queries are wrapped into sp_executesql and still have parameters. But the captured text is executable, so it might be a partial solution.

Comment: Yes, they'll still have parameters. But if you look at the profile information, you should be able to see what those parameters are, giving you all the information you need to re-run them directly against the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Hibernating Rhinos Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) (commercial software) or you could do this:

```
var query = context.Customers.Where(...);
((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)  query).ToTraceString();
```

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2011/11/seeing-the-sql.aspx